# Is there a way to lock block execution based on SQL query?

Tags: java, spring, jpa, transactions, microservices

Background:
I have a mini-chat app that allows you to create chat rooms for many interlocutors. The chat room for a given set of interlocutors can be created only once, so if the request for creating a chat room with the same set of interlocutors would be executed two times, then only one chat room must be created:

so:

- HTTP POST /chat-rooms for interlocutor1 and interlocutor2 -> creates chat room
- HTTP POST /chat-rooms for interlocutor1 and interlocutor2 -> skip creating room, because already exists

Basically, it is a simple many-to-many relationship, there are three tables: chat_rooms, chat_room_interlocutor, and interlocutors

When using a single thread environment, all seems to be ok, however, on the multithread, I end up with duplicated chat rooms for the same set of interlocutors. This seems to be a classic concurrency problem that could be fixed by a locking mechanism, however when two or more microservice instances are available, then locking should be delegated to the database level.

Because I am using Spring Boot, I have tried use     `@Lock(LockModeType.PESSIMISTIC_READ)`
on the JPA query, however, the second thread does not hang on the query and creates duplicated chat room. The query looks like this:

```
select c.chat_id from chat c
join chat_interlocutor c1 on  c1.chat_id = c.chat_id and c1.interlocutor_id = ?1
join chat_interlocutor c2 on c2.chat_id = c.chat_id and c2.interlocutor_id = ?2
```

The whole scenario looks like this:

Microservice1

1. Check if chat between two interlocutors exists ( interlocutor1 and interlocutor2)
2. It does not exists, so create it

Microservice2

1. Check if chat between two interlocutors exists ( interlocutor1 and interlocutor2), [here microservice1 did not commit yet]
2. It does not exist, so create it  [here we are creating duplicated chat room]

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32336481/table-exclusive-lock-with-jpa may help.  Beyond that, if chat room creation doesn't happen that frequently, it might make sense to put the `POST /chat-room` endpoint into its own single-thread, single-instance service.

Answer (score 0):

You're simplest solution would be to use a unique chat-room id in the database as a synchronisation mechanism (as that is shared between the microservices).

For that to work, you will have to create a chat-room entity when a session is started. You'll have to ensure it will always be created with a unique ID that is determined from the 2 participants. If the create worked, then this is a new chat-room, if there was a unique key violation then the chat-room already exists.

The flow you described is almost correct, but you missed the creation of the chat-room in the database with a unique id built by the microservice. You still would want to check if the chat-room already exists, as that will avoid too many create conflicts.