# How to set a lock for the entire entity or table in hibernate

Tags: java, spring, hibernate, spring-data-jpa

I want to lock a table at the entity level in Hibernate/Spring Data JPA.

This is a mock-up of my code:

```
@Entity
@Data
@Table(name = "Armor")
public class Armor {
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    private Long id;
    @OptimisticLocking
    private String armorBrand;
}
```

Can I do this but for the entire table?

I'm currently using JpaRepository for my updates. I would like to keep using it instead of EntityManager.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Table exclusive lock with JPA](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32336481/table-exclusive-lock-with-jpa)

Comment: This isn't what I want. I'm using JpaRepository right now. Is there a solution that doesn't make me use EntityManager?

Comment: No there is no solution that locks the table

Comment: Shouldn't this depends on the database you are using? For example MySQL when using InnoDB it will be using row lock and for myISAM it will lock the whole table? So I would say this is database dependent and nothing to do with Hibernate

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Maybe `@Lock` is what you are looking for.

```
@Lock(LockModeType.PESSIMISTIC_READ)
public Optional<Armor> findById(Long armorId);
```

Comment: This will not lock the table

Comment: @SimonMartinelli This does allow me to use JpaRepository. I think it's a good compromise.

Comment: But why initally did you want to lock the whole table?

Comment: @SimonMartinelli Because I've written dozens of queries that have caused a concurrency/deadlock issue. It's either I lock the table or the queries or I will need to rewrite some of the code

Answer (score 0):

Use the following:

```
setLockMode(String alias, LockMode lockMode)
```

Comment: Is there a way to do this using JpaRepository and not EntityManager? @Andres