# JPA : How to acquire lock on table without lock annotation in repository

Tags: java, spring-boot, jpa, locking, jdbctemplate

In my project I am using springboot and JPA.

In my project I have a table T, which can be updated from two methods A and B. A & B are implemented in service layer So I cannot use lock annotation as we can use lock annotation only on repository level.

A() {

Updating table T

}

B() {
Updating table T

}

Method A and B are called from two different API. I need to acquire lock on table T while my method B is executing and if in meantime someone calls method A then he should wait until method B complete.

I also have JDBCtemplate instance In my project, in case if we can achieve locking by JDBC.

In my method B I am disabling and enabling my constraint So I want to acquire lock on table so there will be no chance of duplicate records.

Please help

Comment: Not sure what is blocking you from using annotations on repository level, but you can handle locking programmatically on entityManager api. Compare i.e. https://dzone.com/articles/concurrency-and-locking-with-jpa-everything-you-ne

Comment: @MatthiasWiedemann Hi thanks for reply. I am exchanging lots of data from one table to other using exchange command for that I am Disable and enable constraint At service level. Not sure how to do the same while doing a repository level

Comment: Ok locking the whole table seems not supported by jpa. See solution with lockEntity suggested in https://stackoverflow.com/a/32348554/2290153

Comment: Another locking implementation technique other than jpa could be hazelcast https://docs.hazelcast.com/imdg/4.2/data-structures/fencedlock