# Use pessimistic locking for several operations at the same time

Tags: java, spring-boot, hibernate, jpa

I'm using Spring Boot + JPA + Hibernate and I need to perform the following two operations in a table:

- Remove all table records
- Insert new records

It is really easy using `CrudRepository#deleteAll()` and `JpaRepository#saveAll(Iterable<S> entities)`. However, I need to ensure pessimistic locking is used during the whole process. I know how to specify locking mode for any of those method, but I have no clue on how to wrap both methods into an atomic process to guarantee the pessimistic locking... How could I achieve that?

Comment: What do you want to lock during creation phase if there is nothing to lock yet?

Comment: @Antoniossss I need to ensure there are no other processes reading or writing during the whole process. To be clear, every time anyone queries the table, there must be records... so this process of removing and inserting should be transparent

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/32348554/1527544 - you would have to lock table

Comment: to ensure pessimistic locking is used during the whole process specify locking mode.

Comment: @K.Nicholas where do I specify the locking mode? Because all the info I've seen is at JPARepository level, but I need to wrap both processes (delete and insert) into the same locking

Comment: locking is at JPARepository level, but you need to wrap both processes into the same transaction.

Comment: You seem like such a nice young man. Has anyone told you about the pessimistic lockings and transactions yet?